# How to create discord category with permissions using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with discord.js. I want to create a new category with multiple permissions and multiple roles. And I'm facing problems in doing so.

I tried many ways but not working.

Here a code:

```
function makeChannel(message){
    var server = message.guild;
    server.createChannel('test', {
        type: 'category',
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: '671725307836891166',
            deny: ['PRIORITY_SPEAKER'],
            allow: [{
                ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'],
                ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
                ['MANAGE_ROLES'],
                ['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'],
                ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                ['SEND_TTS_MESSAGES'],
                ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
                ['EMBED_LINKS'],
                ['ATTACH_FILES'],
                ['READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                ['MENTION_EVERYONE'],
                ['USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS'],
                ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
                ['CONNECT'],
                ['SPEAK'],
                ['MUTE_MEMBERS'],
                ['DEAFEN_MEMBERS'],
                ['MOVE_MEMBERS'],
                ['USE_VAD'],
                ['STREAM']
            }]
        }]
    })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

With above code, I'm getting the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaVsG.png

I tried allow parameter with following values, but still, it throws the error:

`allow: 'permission', 'permission', 'permission'`

`allow: [{ 'permission', 'permission', 'permission' }]`

`allow: ['permission'], ['permission'], ['permission']`

I think it only allows 1 allowed and 1 denied permission to be specified. But I wanna do with more.

Or you have any idea how to set these permissions to the created categories?

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord APIs but it seems like there is a syntax error in your code. The value of `allow` parameter is not a valid value and therefore it is throwing the error that you attached in the image. The error that you posted is not related to discord.

Comment: I know thats the syntax error. But i think 'allow' line it can only 1 permission allowed to use. And I need help different way to set more permission at the same time to category.

(Thanks editing my topic. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```js
allow: [
  'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
  'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
  'MANAGE_ROLES',
  'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
  'VIEW_CHANNEL',
  'SEND_MESSAGES',
  'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
  'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
  'EMBED_LINKS',
  'ATTACH_FILES',
  'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
  'MENTION_EVERYONE',
  'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
  'ADD_REACTIONS',
  'CONNECT',
  'SPEAK',
  'MUTE_MEMBERS',
  'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
  'MOVE_MEMBERS',
  'USE_VAD',
  'STREAM'
]
```

You also don't need to put `'PRIORITY_SPEAKER'` in an array, so this can be your permission overwrite:

```js
{
  id: '671725307836891166',
  deny: 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER',
  allow: [
    'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
    'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
    'MANAGE_ROLES',
    'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
    'VIEW_CHANNEL',
    'SEND_MESSAGES',
    'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
    'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
    'EMBED_LINKS',
    'ATTACH_FILES',
    'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
    'MENTION_EVERYONE',
    'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
    'ADD_REACTIONS',
    'CONNECT',
    'SPEAK',
    'MUTE_MEMBERS',
    'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
    'MOVE_MEMBERS',
    'USE_VAD',
    'STREAM'
  ]
}
```